# Lravel Mail not sending -- Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, gmail

I just developed a laravel web application with mail system. 
i got error like

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

controller

```
Mail::send('timesheet/emailtemplate',array('data'=>$query),function($message) 
    {
$message->to('example@gmail.com')->cc('expalecc@gmail.com')->subject('Work Report on - ');
    });
```

email template file : emailtemplate.blade.php

```
<h2>hai</h2>
```

mail.php  (config)

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'myemail@example.com',
'password' => 'mypassword',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using smtp use **Mandrill Driver** it is simpler and quicker than use smtp server. by default laravel comes with Mandrill Driver. mandrill required Guzzle 4 HTTP library.. for geting that into your project add

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"
```

to your *composer.json* file (in your project root directory)

[image]

inside *app/config/mail.php*

change this line

```
'driver' => 'mandrill',
```

go to https://mandrillapp.com/settings
and sign up and **generate api key**

create an app/config/services.php configuration file if one does not already exist for your project and add below configurations and generated api key

```
return array(

'mailgun' => array(
    'domain' => '',
    'secret' => '',
),

'mandrill' => array(
    'secret' => 'enter your mandrill api key here',
),

'stripe' => array(
    'model'  => 'User',
    'secret' => '',
),

);
```

check this out this will be help full
[Youtube video for setting up Mandrill for laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb0AGSh8qnw)

Comment: also how to remove **via mail100.us4.mandrillapp.com** in mail

Comment: app/config/mail.php 

`'from' => array('address' => 'whatever@gmail.com', 'name' => 'webAdmin'),`

change this line :)

Comment: i already set that in mail.php but in ail i receive it shows. **Naveen demo@test.com via mail100.us4.mandrillapp.com**

Comment: ohh [sending-domains](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-domains)

[how to set sending-domains](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21681347-how-do-i-set-up-sending-domains) I don't know how it works on localhost :(

Comment: This answer now is outdated as mandrill is a paid add-on from MailChimp.