# Laravel's Mail not working but PHP mail() does

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to send mails using Laravel's Mail class. 
I've set driver to `mail` in the config, but the mails won't send.

This is my Laravel code with the `Mail` function:

```
foreach ($registered as $invite) {
    Mail::queue('emails.invites.registered', $invite, function ($msg) use ($invite) {
        $msg->to($invite['email'], $invite['name'])->subject('Subject');
    });
};
```

When I try to manually use the `mail()` function of PHP the server does send the email.

What could be wrong in this case? Laravel's Mail class is using the `mail()` function as well, right?

**If I set pretending to true, the log says the mail will be send as well.**

Comment: I bet if you included a code sample of you calling Laravel's mail function that someone here would be more willing to help you with your question.

Comment: the possibilities are close to infinite

Answer (score 0):

if you use "mail". Also put the host as blank.

```
'host' => ' ',
```

First of all Try to send without queue

```
Mail::send('emails.invites.registered', ['invite' => $invite], function($msg)
{
    $msg->to($invite['email'], $invite['name'])->subject('Subject');
});
```

Comment: check my mandrill api mail send and try it. that's the help I can give you [Mandrill mail laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346788/lravel-mail-not-sending-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gm/28357715#28357715)